# 90s-2000s vampire movie where rich vampires drink bottled blood like it's wine?

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

It's probably from late 90s or early 2000s, East Asian movie where aristocratic vampires drink bottled blood and live among humans.

I just remember a scene. The hero vampire falls for a girl and she insists on going on a date in daytime. He dresses in layers to avoid the direct sun but when they step out, the guy starts to steam.

It was probably a comedy, and had good action.

Answer (score 5):

*The Twins Effect* (2003).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twins_Effect):

> **An evil vampire duke seeks to kill and collect the blood of a royal family of European vampires in order to become all powerful.** The last surviving member of the family, Prince Kazaf, flees to Hong Kong with his servant Prada. There, they are introduced by estate agent Momoko to live in an abandoned church.
>
> Vampire hunter Reeve is depressed after his partner Lila is killed by vampires. He decides to train Lila's younger sister, Gypsy, to inherit her sister's duty and fight the vampire duke. However, Reeve's own sister, Helen, sees Gypsy as a rival.
>
> At the same time, **Kazaf meets Helen and falls in love with her, after which he intends to lead the life of a human being**, but he is tracked down by the duke. Helen helps Kazaf and lets him hide in her home, where they are later discovered by Gypsy. Meanwhile, Reeve falls into the duke's trap while hunting vampires. Helen and Gypsy team up to save him.

[IMDb's detailed summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0351887/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_stry_pl) has the bits about the wine and daytime date:

> Helen collapses at a table occupied by two guys and **swigs down a glass of their wine.** What Helen doesn't know is that the guys are the Fifth Prince of the Vampire Nation, Kazaf Edison Chen, and his attendant Prada Anthony Chau-Sang Wong, that they are both vampires, and that **the wine she just drank is actually blood.** Fortunately, Helen is too upset to notice the taste, and Kazaf is so charmed by her that he instantly falls in love, so much so that he asks for her phone number. **Prince Kazaf isn't one of those common vampires who suck blood out of people's necks. In fact, his dad sends him a case of Chateau Grimon blood every week.** [...]
>
> But Helen is getting over the bum pretty quickly, especially after Kazaf calls her and **asks for a date...at noon tomorrow. No problem for Helen, but a big problem for Kazaf, who cannot go out in the sun**. [...] That afternoon, Kazaf, **slathered with sunscreen**, keeps his date with Helen.

The movie is available on YouTube, the wine scene starts at 17:58 and 21:18, the date in a coat, hat and sunscreen at 35:56 and the steaming (not steamy!) vampire at 43:16.

---

Found with the Google query `asian vampire movie aristocratic`. Among the images results, the poster for this movie (rightly) seemed to match the comedy/action type:

[image: movie poster, six characters with seemingly voluntary cliché blades, sunglasses, trenchcoats]

Comment: Jackie Chan makes an appearance at 37:40 https://youtu.be/O_vqJ6hT1Qs?t=2260